# Why are new forms ASPX? - should be XSN

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

Recently SPD2010 has started creating workflow task forms as .aspx. Previously they were .xsn - which I need them to be - the forms must be editable in InfoPath.

What might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: SOLVED: I had foolishly switched off one of the Workflow features at the site collection level, turned it back on and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on Publishing Approval Workflow in site collection features.